# Can't change tag of fragment Error - Trying to use a PagerAdapter for switching

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I read the last our about this problem but didn't find a solution that helped, i just don't understand what the problem is.
The code already worked, but it seems like some following work has destoryed it, then i deleted every change i've made but i get still this Error.
I hope someone knows more about this problem and can help me.

```
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment CardFragment{426ce8a0 #1 id=0x7f0e001f android:switcher:2131623967:1}: was android:switcher:2131623967:1 now android:switcher:2131623967:2
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:399)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:390)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:103)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-22 22:59:01.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the code in MainActivity where i use MyPagerAdapter for the Fragments

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_logo);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);

    mColors = new int[]{
            R.color.myGreen,
            R.color.blue,
            R.color.orange,
            R.color.red,
            R.color.green,
    };

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    //use the database
    openDB();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    closeDB();
}

private void closeDB() {
    myDB.close();
}

private void openDB() {
    myDB = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDB.open();
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        TITLES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
        case 0: cardF0 = new CardFragment(TITLES[0], mColors[0]); return cardF0;
        case 1: cardF1 = new CardFragment(TITLES[1], mColors[0]); return cardF1;
        case 2: return cardF1;
        }
        return cardF0;
    }
}
```

EDIT: forgot to post the vars

```
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
private ViewPager pager;
private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
private static CardFragment cardF0;
private static CardFragment cardF1;
```

Comment: is cardF0 & cardF1 member variables of your activity?

Comment: oh yes sorry, i forgot to post them.

Comment: whats the size of the TITLES array

Comment: The array has 3 values .. Case 2 is just again cardF1 because before there was a diffrent Fragment and i thought that this could be the reason.

Comment: [Read this one. You will get the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345129/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-change-tag-of-fragment/59835511#59835511)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[I think this link can explain whats happening here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345129/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-change-tag-of-fragment)

> It's probably because you're adding the same fragment instance three
>   times to the list. You should create a new instance for each page.

Since you have 3 items in the array, but returning 2 fragments, where 1 re-used fragment gets returned over & over again sharing the same tag likely causes this exception.  So just make new instances, and let the adapter handle the memory efficiency for you.

Also, do not make your fragments static, or else their context (container activity) can never be released in memory, causing huge activity memory leaks.

Comment: By the way.. do you know a proper way to show a new fragment when a item is pressed in the current fragment, in the implementation like i have it?

Comment: In the fragment thats being clicked, do a getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...) & so forth, basically the container activity will still be handling the fragment transaction, even though the event will occur in the fragment.  When performing the transaction use the addToBackStack() if you want to preserve the previous fragment's instance if users hit the back button.

Comment: It works perfectly and it even resolved another problem I was facing which was the **disappearance of fragments** (pager displays no view)!!
so thumb up!