# IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment was android:switcher now android:switcher

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentpageradapter

My activity uses `TabLayout` + `ViewPager`.

The number of tabs and pages here are dynamic depending on the data fetch from the server.

The crash are reported via Crashlytics,  I'm not able to replicate it.

My Activity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean isAppRestarting = PrefUtils.getBoolean("app_restarting", false);
        if (isAppRestarting) {
            super.onCreate(null);
            this.savedInstanceState = null;
        } else {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        }

        initSlidingTabs();

        fetchSomeData(); // see onDataFetched() below
    }

private void initSlidingTabs() {
        List<FragmentWithTitle> sdsTabs = new ArrayList<>();
            Logger.i("There is saved instance state");
            ArrayList<String> titles = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(TAB_TITLES);
            if (titles != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
                    if (getFragment(i) != null) {
                        sdsTabs.add(new FragmentWithTitle(getFragment(i), titles.get(i)));
                    }
                }
            }

        mTabsAdapter = new MyTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), sdsTabs);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.layoutViewPagerSlidingTabs);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        mSlidingTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mSlidingTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mTabsAdapter != null) {
            outState.putStringArrayList(TAB_TITLES, mTabsAdapter.getTitles());
        }
    }

    private Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        return savedInstanceState == null ? mTabsAdapter.getItem(position) : getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(position));
    }

    private String getFragmentTag(int position) {
        return "android:switcher:" + R.id.layoutViewPagerSlidingTabs + ":" + position;
    }

/**
Callback of fetchData() in onCreate()
*/
private void onDataFetched(List<AbcObject> abcObjects) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            if (abcObjects != null) {
                for (AbcObject abcObject : abcObjects) {
                    mTabsAdapter.addTab(new FragmentWithTitle(AbcFragment.newInstance(), abcObject.getTitle()));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Logger.d("There is saved instance state");
            ArrayList<String> titles = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(TAB_TITLES);
            if (titles != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
                    mTabsAdapter.addTab(new FragmentWithTitle(getFragment(i), titles.get(i)));
                }
            }
        }

        mTabsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

MyTabsAdapter:

```
public class MyTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<FragmentWithTitle> mTabs = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<FragmentWithTitle> sdsTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mTabs = sdsTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mTabs.get(position).getFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTabs.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mTabs.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    /**
     * Prevent java.lang.IllegalStateException Fragment no longer exists for key android:target_state: index 5
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTitles() {
        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            titles.add((String) mTabs.get(i).getTitle());
        }
        return titles;
    }

    public void addTab(FragmentWithTitle fragmentWithTitle) {
        mTabs.add(fragmentWithTitle);
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment ShopFrag{4dbb6e90 #0 id=0x7f1200dd android:switcher:2131886301:0}: was android:switcher:2131886301:0 now android:switcher:2131886301:9
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:444)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:426)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:103)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1038)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1252)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17396)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6401)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

FragmentWithTitle:

```
public class FragmentWithTitle {
    public FragmentWithTitle(Fragment mFragment, CharSequence mTitle) {
        this.fragment = mFragment;
        this.title = mTitle;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment() {
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    private Fragment fragment;
    private CharSequence title;
}
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like: [Can't change tag of fragment Error - Trying to use a PagerAdapter for switching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355838/cant-change-tag-of-fragment-error-trying-to-use-a-pageradapter-for-switching).

Comment: I know, read that but I cannot apply anything from the answer there @Tigger

Comment: Please add your class `FragmentWithTitle`

Comment: @eric read this article...You might come up with some workaround https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/looping-infinite-viewpager-with-page-indicator-in-android-ce741f25702a#.ipllsqvh6

Comment: thanks @PN10 but it has nothing to do with my problem

Comment: Can the person who downvoted my question come forward with a comment please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `FragmentPagerAdapter` already caches the `Fragments` for you. Each fragment is assigned a tag, and then the `FragmentPagerAdapter` tries to call `findFragmentByTag`. It only calls **getItem()** if the result from `findFragmentByTag` is `null`.

*You're probably getting this error because you're adding the same fragment instance to the list. You should create a **new instance** for each page.*

Example form document :

```
//...
      public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return NUM_ITEMS;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);// IMPORTANT
            }
        }
    //..
```

Refer :[FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)

Main thread : [Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager/15261142#15261142)

Comment: Thanks @Charuක, is there any drawback in terms of memory management?

Comment: @eric you mean by returning new instance i guess no, it gets called only findFragmentByTag is null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339500/when-is-fragmentpageradapters-getitem-called  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581896/fragmentpageradapter-getitem-is-not-called

Comment: Please check the size of fragment name_array and adapter size. It would be resolve the issue.