# How to update value from Fragment to Activity from single Fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am writing followings code for `PagerAdapter`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment_edit_delivery_location = new Fragment_edit_delivery_location_Map();
            Bundle arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putString("delivery_to_title_map", "Map Location");
            fragment_edit_delivery_location.setArguments(arg);
            return fragment_edit_delivery_location;


        case 1:
            fragment_edit_delivery_locationHome = new Fragment_edit_delivery_locationHome();
            Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
            arg1.putString("delivery_to_title_home", "Home");
            fragment_edit_delivery_location.setArguments(arg1);
            return fragment_edit_delivery_location;
}
}
```

I am getting error as error
***[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment Fragment_edit_delivery_location_Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l83bo.jpg)***

**Constructor of adapter**

```
public ActionTabAdapter( FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
}
```

**I am using `ViewPager` in MainActivity as :**

```
adapter = new ActionTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am trying to get dynamic value From current **Fragment** and again used in MainActivity to send String value as intent From **MainActivity** to **SecondActivity** .....but also not being able to get accurate value from Current Frgment .....Any kind of help is appreciated Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345129/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-change-tag-of-fragment

Comment: Think MVC pattern. Build a custom adapter and pass a model object to it that holds the values shown in the fragments. Make the fragments write back changes to the model object. Since the activity was creating the adapter in the first place, it also has access to the model object. *Don't try to pass information "across" views, you will get hurt.*

Comment: Use static factory methods for your fragments instead of constructing them client side. Its also an easy mechanism to add arguments to as well.

Answer (score 0):

use call backs would help you out

1) create an interface

```
public interface TextCallback {
void getcalltochangeText(String txt);
void getArrayToset(ArrayList<String> data);
```

}

2) In your fragment class put this way
TextCallback textCallback;

textCallback.getcalltochangeText("BREW TEA");

```
   @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if(activity instanceof FragmentCommunicator)
    {


        fc=(FragmentCommunicator)activity;

    }
    else
    {
        throw  new  ClassCastException();
    }

    if(activity instanceof TextCallback)
    {
        textCallback=(TextCallback)activity;
    }
    else
    {
        throw  new  ClassCastException();

    }
}
```

3) And then in you main activity implement this interface

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener ,TextCallback



@Override
public void getcalltochangeText(String txt) {
// here you can get passed values from fragment
    setReceivedMsg(txt);
}
```

// and get the values here that you want