# Add new fragments to left and right side of viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a calendar application. Each month is one `Fragment`. I'm using `ViewPager` and `FragmentPageAdapter`. I want to add one `Fragment` when swiping to the left and position is 2 and I want to add one `Fragment` when swiping to the right and position is `fragments.size() - 2`.

I have no problem to add `Fragment` to the right but the problem occurs when adding to 0 position because of [Can't change tag of fragment exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345129/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-change-tag-of-fragment). I was looking to the solution to the problem with no success. I'm wondering if there is some alternative to `ViewPager` or another solution to this problem.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, int position) {
        fragments.add(position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        fragments.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.remove(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with third party library

Comment: do you have some recommendation? cause I haven't found a suitable one